# java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification exception thrown

Tags: java, exception, for-loop

when running the code below i get the above exception but i don't know why or how to fix it. 
Im pretty sure it comes from

```
    for(int node : adjacent(currentnode))
        {
            //System.out.println(adjacent(currentnode));
            //System.out.println(node);
            if (remainingnodes.contains(getNode(node)))
            {
                adjacent.add(node);
                remainingnodes.remove(getNode(node));
                //System.out.println(remainingnodes);
            }
        }
```

getNode just takes an integer and returns the corresponding node. I used to not get the exception before i used getNode in remainingnodes.contains but at the time it was removing the components so i had to change it and now i get the exception.

```
public int distance(int target, List<Integer> detectives)
{
    List<Integer> adjacent = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Node<Integer>> remainingnodes = new HashSet<Node<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> currentnodes = new ArrayList<>();

    int distance = 0;
    int i = 0;



    currentnodes.add(target);
    remainingnodes = graph.getNodes();
    remainingnodes.remove(getNode(target));

    while (detectives.size() != 0)
    {

        for (int currentnode : currentnodes)
        {

            for(int node : adjacent(currentnode))
            {
                //System.out.println(adjacent(currentnode));
                //System.out.println(node);
                if (remainingnodes.contains(getNode(node)))
                {
                    adjacent.add(node);
                    remainingnodes.remove(getNode(node));
                    //System.out.println(remainingnodes);
                }
            }
            for (int detective : detectives)
            {
                if (currentnode == detective)
                {
                    distance = distance + i;
                    detectives.remove(detective);
                }
            }
        }

    currentnodes.clear();
    currentnodes = adjacent;
    i++;
    }
```

Thanks 
Arthur

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `ConcurrentModificationException`? I've never heard of a `CoModificationException`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cant modify the `List` in for each loop. If you want to remove any elements in loop use `iterator`. You can remove elements using `iterator.remove();` which deletes current element in the `iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

As you are itterating over a list and trying to remove element from the same list, a `ConcurrentModificationException` shall occur.

You first iterate over the list then you determine the position of the element you want to remove from list and store it in a temporary variable, then after the iteration is complete, just remove the particular element based on stored position.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. While iterating over a `List`, you *cannot* alter it, like you are doing when calling `adjacent.add(node)` inside the for loop.

This is called concurrent modification, thus the exception [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).